Javascript scroll effect
I have the following code, which I have integrated as an iframe. By scrolling, images are loaded one after the other. after the last image, I would like the page to continue scrolling, as I have more content at the bottom. it does that, but I either have to move the mouse a little and scroll or scroll several times. does anyone have a solution for this?


const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("3d");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 27;
const currentFrame = index => (
  `https://www.in-visionen.de/Webdesign/Webdesign${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width = 3840;
canvas.height = 2160;
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

const updateImage = index => {
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
  );

  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});

preloadImages()
.art {
  height: 100vh;
}

.design {
  height: 200vh;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 80vw;
  max-height: 80vh;
}
<div class="art">
  <div class="design">
    <canvas id="3d">
</canvas>
  </div>
</div>




I made a snippet of your code however note that <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> can simply be <script> as all modern browsers default to JavaScript now days.

You may wish to add some content that is scrollable to better illustrate the issue

FWIW you can elimiate canvas {   position: fixed;   left: 50%;   top: 50%;   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   max-width: 80vw;   max-height: 80vh; } entirely if you use the .design styled as a grid and super centered .desgn{display:grid; place-items:center;}

I think you can use IntersectionObserver here; I started to put an answer in but will need to come back later as I get time to do so

Hey Mark Schultheiss, thnaks... i will wait for the code... I am a beginner and i understand not so much about javescript, but i want to have this design...
